# List button in Salesforce1

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-ios-sdk

In Salesforce1, Is there an option to add custom List button? For example, follow below steps and you will land to Opportunity tab in Salesforce1 and I want to see button at the bottom(refer screenshot).

Step 1 : Login to Salesforce1 using any dev sanbox
Step 2 : Tap on Navigation menu 
Step 3 : Tap on Opportunities

You will see below button UI:[image: Salesforce1 Opportunity tab]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I raised a case with Salesforce support regarding this. Currently this is not possible. They have taken this as an Idea. Feel free to vote and promote this idea.

https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000DpZwAAK

For more information regarding your inquiry please reference the Knowledge Base Article below or you can search the Help & Training link in the upper right corner by using key words:

Salesforce1 - Are Custom Buttons/Links Supported in the Salesforce1 App?:
https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?urlname=Salesforce1-Are-Custom-Buttons-Links-Supported-in-the-Salesforce1-App&language=en_US

Salesforce1 - Custom buttons & overrides support:
https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?urlname=Salesforce1-Custom-buttons-overrides-support&language=en_US

Answer (score 0):

Well here is a link to the help page that explains how to create a custom button:
https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=defining_custom_links.htm&language=en_US

I don't know if you can access this exact link, if not you can find it in the help section of salesforce. Good Luck!